# Angular Firestore - I want get document ID's of collection and convert them to an array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to convert all my document ID's to an array so I can do perform `array.includes()` query.

**this is my code -**

```js
this.db.collection('camps', ref => ref.where('id', '==', "fxvb95"))
  .snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => { 
    data.forEach(doc => {
      const y = doc.payload.doc.data()['altUID'];
      console.log(y)
  });
```

**this is result in log**

`exampleUID1`

`exampleUID2`

How do i change these into single value or an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```js
this.db
  .collection("camps", (ref) => ref.where("id", "==", "fxvb95"))
  .snapshotChanges()
  .subscribe((data) => {
    const myArray = [];
    data.forEach((doc) => {
      const y = doc.payload.doc.data()["altUID"];
      console.log(y);
      myArray.push(y);
    });
    console.log(myArray);
  });
```

Comment: why not use map method of the array? `myArray=data.map(doc=>doc.payload.doc.data()["altUID"])`

Answer (score 0):

Using AngularFire

```
import { Firestore, collection, collectionData } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

Service

```
getCamps(): Observable<[]> {
  const collectionRef = collection(this.firestore, 'camps');
  return collectionData(collectionRef, { idField: 'id'}) as Observable<[]>; 
}
```

Component

```
this.dbService.getCamps().subscribe(data => {
  data.forEach(doc => {
    this.myArray.push(doc.id);
  });
})
```